# Convert generator to normal function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working on a project and there is some refactor to do. For internal decision we do not want to use generators and I came across this code (which it looks weird to me because it seems that there is no need for a generator at all). How would I go to convert it to a normal function (I don't think there is any async operation as far as I can tell)?

Just to make clear I do not want to use generators in this code.

Code:

```
const getResults = (totalData) => function* getNext() { 
    const combinations = totalData.reduce((a, b) => a * b.length, 1) 
    for (let i = 0; i < combinations; i++) { 
        yield createSolution(i, totalData) 
    } 
    return null 
}
```

This is how is being called:

```
const result = getResults(obj.elementsInObj);

    for (let data of result()) {
        const resolve = validateData(data, obj.elementsInObj)
        if (resolve) {
            return resolve
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick thing to note that I picked up from `prefer-const`: you can *totally* use `for (const data of result())` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can remove the asterisk and `yield` operator and create an internal array to store the `solutions`, then you can return that array and loop over it.

```
const getResults = (totalData) => {
  const combinations = totalData.reduce((a, b) => a * b.length, 1),
        arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < combinations; i++) arr.push(createSolution(i, totalData));
  return arr;
}

const results = getResults(obj.elementsInObj);
for (let data of results) {
  const resolve = validateData(data, obj.elementsInObj)
  if (resolve) return resolve
}
```

Comment: This! Thank you so much